# Не корректно работает постраничный вывод из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>База данных</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<p>
с даты: <input type="text" name="fromdate" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['fromdate'] ?>" />
по дату: <input type="text" name="todate" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['todate'] ?>"/>
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Поиск"/>
</p>
</form>

<?php
require_once("bd.php");
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Далее сам `bd.php`:

```
<?php 
$msql = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","employees");
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) )
{   
   $fromdate=$_POST['fromdate'];
   $todate = $_POST['todate'];

   $limitrec=15; // количество записей на одной странице
   $limit=3; 
   $page = $_GET['page'];
   if(!is_numeric($page)) $page=1;
   if ($page<1) $page=1;
   $sqlcount = "SELECT COUNT(salaries.emp_no) as cmt FROM salaries 
        INNER JOIN employees ON salaries.emp_no=employees.emp_no 
        WHERE ((salaries.from_date>='$fromdate') and (salaries.to_date<='$todate'))"; // узнаём количество записей
   $r = $msql->query($sqlcount);
   $i = $r->fetch_row();
   $pages = $i[0]/$limitrec;
   $pages = ceil($pages);

   $pages++;   
   if ($page>$pages) $page = 1;
   if (!isset($list)) $list=0;
   $list=($page-1)*$limitrec;    
   $sql = "SELECT salaries.emp_no, salaries.salary, salaries.from_date, salaries.to_date, employees.first_name,employees.last_name
        FROM salaries INNER JOIN employees ON salaries.emp_no=employees.emp_no 
        WHERE ((salaries.from_date>='$fromdate') and (salaries.to_date<='$todate')) LIMIT $list, $limitrec ";  

   $res = $msql->query($sql);

   $_this = $page;
   // Узнаем с какой ссылки начинать вывод
   $start = $_this - $limit;
   // Узнаем номер последней ссылки для вывода
   $end = $_this + $limit;
   $pages++;
   // Выводим ссылки на все страницы
   for ($j = 1; $j <= $pages; $j++) 
   {
      if ($j >= $start && $j <= $end) 
      {
         if ($j == ($page)) 
         {
            echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?page='.$j.'"><strong style="color: #df0000">'.$j.'</strong></a>';
         }
         else 
         {
            echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?page='.$j.'">'.$j.'</a>';
         }
      }
   }
   $table = "</br><table border=1 width ='600px' align=left> <tr><th>Номер</th> <th>Зарплата</th> <th>С даты</th> <th>По дату</th> <th>Имя</th> <th>Фамилия</th></tr>";
   if ($i > 1){
     while($row = $res->fetch_array()){
        $table .= "<tr>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['emp_no']."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['salary']."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['from_date']."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['to_date']."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['first_name']."</td>";
        $table .= "<td>".$row['last_name']."</td>";
        $table .= "</tr>"; 
    }
} else {
    echo '<tr>Ничего не найдено</tr>';
}

$table .= "</table>";
echo $table;       
}
```

Первая страница выводится нормально, а вот чтобы записи вывелись при переходе на вторую страницу приходиться снова вводить даты и нажимать поиск, может кто подскажет как сделать, чтобы при переходе на следующую страницу записи выводились сразу?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Даты теряются, потому что в ссылках на страницы нет этих параметров.

1. Переделайте форму на `method="get"`.
2. Во всех местах $_POST и $_REQUEST замените на $_GET
3. Там где у вас цикл вывода ссылок на страницы, сделайте ссылку так:

.

```
echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?" . 
    http_build_query(array(
        'page'     => $j,
        'fromdate' => $_GET['fromdate'],
        'todate'   => $_GET['todate'],
    )) .
"\">{$j}</a>";
```

P.S. Еще лучше выполнять поиск один раз, сохранять результат в кеш и на страницах выводить из кеша, чтобы много раз не выполнять одну и ту же тяжелую операцию.

Comment: теперь почему то программа мне выводит только первую страницу, а при переходе на 2 и т.д. пустота как и раньше, но теперь при вводе данных повторно меня скидывает на первую страницу

Comment: Отлаживайтесь. Где-то что-то упустили. http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Answer (score -1):

Диапазон дат надо как-то передавать от запуска к запуску. можно, как яндекс, писать даты в query и использовать get, а не post. Можно сохранять в сесии